# ejabberd clustering - load balancing between the nodes

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

im new to ejabberd setup. we are using ejabberd in our project and we are getting below performance issue, please assist how we address this.

we have 3 ejabberd servers joined in cluster with LB in front to do the Load balancing between the servers in round-robin
xmppserver1
xmppserver2
xmppserver3

xmppserver1 is master, so requests hitting xmppserver1 are reaching the destination with the same second, but requests reaching xmppserver2 and xmppserver3 are reaching destination after more than 20 sec or getting timed-out(more than 30sec).
please assist how we can handle this so that the request will reach the destination with the seconds even the request reach any server from LB.

we tried sending all requests to xmppserver1 and it was working fast, but when we bring up the other servers the requests hitting 2 and 3 are taking time